# Reversing a Linked List recursively, can someone walk me through it?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public void reverse(Node curr) {
      if (isEmpty()) {
          return;
      }

      if (curr.next == null) {
          head = curr;
          return;
      }

      reverse(curr.next);
      curr.next.next = curr;
      curr.next = null;

  }
```

I'm trying to learn recursion.. my weakest point and I just don't understand how this works... I see that it starts at the 2nd node.. then makes the next, next to the current, and it's link null... i just don't get it.  sorry for the newb question.  i would add more to what i understand.. but that's really about it unfortunately..

Comment: what's the implementation of `isEmpty()`?

Comment: Is this code you wrote, or is it an example from somewhere that is assumed to work?

Comment: an example that i google'd that worked.  just having trouble understanding recursion.  i understand there needs to be a base case.. but as far as understanding and working through it is very difficult for me.

Comment: isEmpty() i'm assuming is just returning if head == null

Comment: If you're *assuming*, how do you know it works?

Comment: because I tried it and it works just fine.

Comment: Then why do you have to *assume*?  Show us exactly what it does instead of *assuming*.  In fact, show us the exact place you found this code so we can get the whole context, not just a part.

Comment: http://www.dontforgettothink.com/2011/11/19/reverse-a-linked-list-in-java/

Comment: i just don't understand what's so important about this assumption.  I tried the code, i implemented isEmpty() as i stated (return head==null) and i mean it's pretty common linked list method?

Comment: @user1189352, I think my answer explains the given code pretty clearly.  Check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to completely ignore your sample code because I also don't understand it.  It's not the easiest way to think about this problem IMO.  Lets think about this conceptually, together:

1. What should happen if someone passes in an empty list?  You should return an empty list
2. What happens if someone returns a list of one element?  You should return what was passed in
3. What happens if someone returns a list of two or more?  You take the *last* element of the list and put it on the front, then you call `last + reverse(listWithLastRemoved)`

---

Lets try this with a list of two.  It has `[a, b]` in it.  You pass it in and step #3 executes.  As a result it does:

```
b + reverse([a])
```

Ignore the left hand side for a second.  `reverse([a])` will return `[a]` because it matches step #2.  That can be evaluated to

```
b + [a]
```

And that can be evaluated to

```
[b, a]
```

Note that **this is pseudocode**.  I'm using `+` to imply adding an element to the front of a list.

---

Lets try it one more time, but this time with 3 elements, `[a b c]`:

```
[a b c] #apply step #3
c + reverse([a b])  #apply step #3
c + b + reverse([a]) #apply step #2
c + b + [a] #add b to [a]
c + [b a] #add c to [b a]
[c b a]
```

---

As you pointed out, to get the last element you'd have to "iterate" the list to find out what's last.  That sounds like you'd have to use a `for` loop (which wouldn't be recursive), but getting the last can be done recursively, too.  In fact, its algorithm is simpler than `reverse` and would have been a better exercise to start with.  I'll explain the steps for `getLast`:

1. What should happen if someone passes in an empty list?  You should return null
2. What happens if someone returns a list of one element?  You should return the first element
3. What happens if someone returns a list of two or more?  You remove the first element of the list, then pass the rest into `getLast`.

Lets try it with `[a b c]`:

```
[a b c] #apply step #3
getLast([b c]) #apply step #3
getLast([c]) #apply step #2
c
```

Notice the last step returns an element, not a list.

Comment: pondering some more, i'm slow at this while i analyze, thanks

Comment: hm that makes it a lot easier to think about it... i'm going to see if i can come up with actual code using these steps in mind.  brb

Comment: @user1189352 That's a good exercise.  Keep in mind if you're new to java this can be tough to do because Java's Collections are usually mutable.  That means that if you pass in a List to a function and then modify the list, all the other functions see the change.

Comment: i think the solution for step 3 that i'm coming with is just too complicated?

i feel like traversing the whole linked list to the very end... then making that the new head and appending the rest of the linked list to it... then it just becomes not recursive at all and seems to take unnecessary steps.. argh.. so frustrated

Comment: it makes sense the way you're writing it.. i guess i'm having trouble figuring out how i can write it "recursively".. going to ponder for a bit....

Comment: @user1189352: no that's fine and *is still* recursive.  Like I said, `reverse` is a tough one to start with.  A better exercise would be to recursively write the `getLast` function that you just described.  You don't have to do that with a for loop if you don't want to.

Comment: ok going to try to write getLast recursively and go from there. brb

Comment: @tieTYT, Check my answer out. Do you get it now?

Comment: public void getLast(Node curr) {
if (curr.next == null) { //last element
System.out.println(curr.data);
return;
}
getLast(curr.next);
}

Comment: hm though i would like it to return a String instead of printing it out... but i don't know how i could do that cus i need a return statement outside of the 'if' statement?  sigh

Comment: is there any way i can talk to your through email or something?  posting code in these small comments doesn't format very well.

Comment: @user1189352 you should edit your question to add your code to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 2):

here is some pseudo code to illustrate a solution

```
// method takes a list and returns the list reversed
// it will corrupt the existing list so do not use it
// after calling this method.
// works by finding the last node and building a list from there
public Node reverseList(Node list){
    // have we found the last node yet?
    if (list.isLast()){
        return list;
    } else {
      // reverse the list after the current node
      Node newList = reverseList(list.next());
      // add current node to end of new list
      addToLast(list,node);
      // return new list
      return newList;
    }

}

public void addToLast(Node list, Node newNode){
    // add newNode to the end of list.
}
```

Comment: hi thank you for this.  haven't looked at this yet as i'm working on tieTYT's answer, will get to this right after though, ty

Answer (score 1):

One way to think of this is with a little example. First, the two edge cases:

1. if the list is empty, it is already reversed (trivially)
2. if `curr` is a single node, it is its own reversal (again, trivially); hence set the current list head to `curr`.

Assuming neither of these holds, then the tricky thing is working out how the last block of code works. Presumably the entire process is initiated by calling `reverse(head)`. Let's see what happens with a two-element list:

```
head = curr(0)
  |
  V
+---+  +---+
| 0 |->| 1 |->null
+---+  +---+
```

Since each recursive call creates a new `curr`, I've annotated `curr` with an index to show what level of recursion applies. Now there's a call to `reverse(curr.next)`. During that call, the picture at the start of the method looks like this:

```
head   curr(1)
  |      |
  V      V
+---+  +---+
| 0 |->| 1 |->null
+---+  +---+
```

This satisfies the second edge case, so the method changes the picture to:

```
       head = curr(1)
         |
         V
+---+  +---+
| 0 |->| 1 |->null
+---+  +---+
```

(Note that although `curr` was a one-element list, that element wasn't `head`. That's key to why the whole thing works!) Now the method returns and we are back at the first call. The picture now looks like this:

```
curr(0) head
  |      |
  V      V
+---+  +---+
| 0 |->| 1 |->null
+---+  +---+
```

The second line of code (in the third block) is `curr.next.next = curr;`. This changes the picture to:

```
curr(0) head
  |      |
  V      V
+---+  +---+
| 0 |->| 1 |--\
+---+  +---+  |
  ^           |
  |           |
  \-----------/
```

Finally, it sets `curr.next = null;`:

```
curr(0)       head
  |             |
  V             V
+---+         +---+
| 0 |->null   | 1 |--\
+---+         +---+  |
  ^                  |
  |                  |
  \------------------/
```

A little staring at that should convince you that the list was, in fact, reversed.

The same technique can be used to see how this reverses longer lists. The easiest way to think about it is that calling `reverse(curr.next)` will reverse the tail of the list and the next two lines will tack on `curr` to the end of the list.

Comment: hi ty for this.  will look at this later. ty

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a walk-through:

```
public void reverse(Node curr) {
      if (isEmpty()) {
          return;
      }
```

If the end of the list has been reached, there is nothing to do.

```
      if (curr.next == null) {
          head = curr;
          return;
      }
```

When the argument is the last node of the list (`curr.next == null`), we set `head` to that node, since the last node of the original is the first node of the reversed list.

```
      reverse(curr.next);
```

Otherwise, we reverse the tail of the list (everything after the current node). The last node of the resulting list is `curr.next`, since that was the first node of the list we reversed here.

```
      curr.next.next = curr;
```

We append the current node to the end of the reversed list. Conveniently, we still have a reference to the last node of that, namely `curr.next`.

```
      curr.next = null;
```

We set the `next` field of the current node to `null`, since it is the last node of the reversed list.

```
}
```

Comment: hi ty for this.  will look at this later. ty

Answer (score 1):

This was a bit odd to me too at first, but it actually makes a lot of sense:

```
public void reverse(Node curr) 
{
      if (isEmpty()) //obvious 
      {
          return;
      }

      if (curr.next == null) //once we get to the last element, assign it to head
      {
          head = curr;
          return;
      }

      //explained below
      reverse(curr.next); 
      curr.next.next = curr;
      curr.next = null;  
  }
```

Let's analyze the last three lines by considering the case when we are on the second to last element.  
We call `reverse(curr.next)`, and since in that call `curr.next == null`, we `head = curr`, in this case `curr` is the last elemtent, and return.
  Now, at `curr.next.next = curr`, `curr` is again the second to last element in the original list.
 `curr.next` is the original last element and `curr.next.next = curr` assigns the second to last element in the original list to be the next element of the last element in the original list. 
`curr.next = null` then makes the `next` element (the third one) in the list `null`.  We repeat and therefore grow the list backwards (the last element will be `null`).

If this still doesn't make sense, try grabbing three objects: pens, books, what have you and use one to represent `curr`, one to represent `curr.next` and one to represent `curr.next.next`/`null`.  It may be helpful if you trace through the calls and use real-life objects to help you keep track of things.  Hope this clears things up.  Good luck.